# How does getting Champion in Apex Legends work?

Tags: apex-legends

I've gotten some pretty amazing wins in Apex with at least 13 kills or more. BUT, somehow a level 47 can take my place as champion even if I did get a lot of kills. How does that even work?

Answer (score 2):

This thread here talks about it being people who won their last game, and if there are multiple, the champion is the one that had the most kills. https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/at873o/who_are_apex_champions/

But if I remember right there was a discussion early on that it was mostly a weighted random because early in the game's life you would get 'champions' that were a party of 3 level 1 players.

Most of what I found were guesses. But I would guess that the reddit thread must be onto something.

Comment: This is what I’ve heard too, but similar to you, I don’t have a credible source